# lua-lockbox aes decryption

Tags: encryption, lua, aes

There is AES encryption function using lua-lockbox lib (https://github.com/somesocks/lua-lockbox)

```
Lockbox = require("lockbox")
Lockbox.ALLOW_INSECURE = true
String = require("string");
Array = require("lockbox.util.array");
Stream = require("lockbox.util.stream");
ECBMode = require("lockbox.cipher.mode.ecb");
ZeroPadding = require("lockbox.padding.zero");
AES128Cipher = require("lockbox.cipher.aes128");
local aes = ECBMode.Cipher();
aes.setKey(Stream.toArray(Stream.fromString("123456789qwertyu")))
aes.setBlockCipher(AES128Cipher)
aes.setPadding(ZeroPadding); 

aes.init() 
aes.update(Stream.fromString("lol"))
aes.finish()
k = aes.asHex()
print(k)
```

How i can decrypt string and get "lol" string?

Comment: Use `ECBMode.Decipher();`

Comment: I tried to use it, but I could not get the original string ("lol")

Comment: How did you use it?  Did you see [examples](https://github.com/somesocks/lua-lockbox/blob/master/test/AES128CipherTests.lua)?

Comment: Yes, I used as in the example, and I get the decrypted string in hex string, but I need to get exactly the original string, not in hex/base64.

Comment: Replace `asHex` with `asBytes` and you'll receive array of bytes.  After that, convert this array to string with `string.char(table.unpack(array_of_bytes))`

Comment: Probably, they should have `asBinaryString` function, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Thanks, it works as it should